# Python3 issue with instantiating a class

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run some example code, but it has issues with instantiating the class Blockchain.  The last time I worked python was 2.7 and I had no problems with the last if statement.

I tried it without the import Blockchain, but creates syntax errors.

Can someone explain what the issue is for 3.8?

Code:

```
    class Blockchain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain = []
        self.pending_transactions = []

    def new_block(self):
        # Create a new Block and adds it to the chain
        pass

    def new_transaction(self):
        # Adds a new transaction to the list of transacations
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def hash(block):
        # Hashes a Block
        pass

    @property
    def last_block(self):
        # Returns the last Block in the chain
        pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import Blockchain
        blockchain = Blockchain()
        print(blockchain.chain)
```

ERROR:
        /Users/denisputnam/PycharmProjects/excersize2/venv/bin/python /Users/denisputnam/PycharmProjects/excersize2/blockchain.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/denisputnam/PycharmProjects/excersize2/blockchain.py", line 1, in 
        class Blockchain:
      File "/Users/denisputnam/PycharmProjects/excersize2/blockchain.py", line 25, in Blockchain
        import Blockchain
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blockchain'

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  The last if has the wrong indentation level. :(